# Reuse part of the same lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have the following case:

```
  //Case 1
  final Set<String> first = A.stream().filter().map().collect()

  //Case 2
  final Set<String> second = B.stream().filter().map().collect()
```

As you can see I call the same lambda expression twice but with different "consumer" (`A` or `B`). Is there a solution to avoid this duplication ?

Comment: What is the type of the expressions `A` and `B` here?  You can probably tie all this up in a method, and just call it.

Comment: Same type, sorry. I forgot to mention it.

Comment: Yes, but what  type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a method, taking a `Collection` of the appropriate type (or a `Stream`, if you don't mind calling `parameter.stream()` when calling the method):

```
Set<String> reuse(Collection<SomeType> collection) {
  return collection.stream().filter().map().collect();
}
```

Then invoke like:

```
final Set<String> first = reuse(A);
final Set<String> second = reuse(B);
```

Comment: This is obvious. I was wondering if there exists something more "fancy".

Comment: Why do you need something fancy if you have something that works and is, as you say, "obvious"? I mean, you could define it as a `Function<Collection<SomeType>, Set<String>> fn = c -> c.stream().filter().map().collect();` inside the method where you use it; but wouldn't that just be messy?

Comment: Just out of my curiosity. I will accept you answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer, and  roughly what I was alluding to in my first comment under the question.

Answer (score 5):

First of all: there are **no** lambdas in your example code.

You are only showing two chained method calls creating a `Set` as final result.

In that sense, the *only* thing that makes sense given the example code: putting the *common* parts

```
return someCollection.stream().filter().map().collect()
```

into a small helper method. Maybe a bit more complex than outlined by Andy - as I expect that the *lambdas* you are talking about are actually used as paramters for the calls to `filter()` and `map()`. In that case you could make those parameters of the helper method.

But as much as I am about avoiding code duplication - you should only create such a helper method when the underlying "semantics" are really identical for the two use cases.

Comment: Yes, understood. Bu I will accept Andy Turner`s answer because he did it first. Thanks a lot for clarification.

Comment: @penguina Fine with me. Andys answers are always great, and he deserves each and any point of reputation flowing in. Guess who was the first person to upvote his answer ...

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Predicate` as a type e.g.

```
Predicate<String> someFilter = e -> e == e; // or something more smart
```

and use it like

```
A.stream().filter(someFilter);
```

Comment: This is not what the OP asked about. He clearly asked for a reusable way of  applying `.stream(). ... .collect()` on objects like `A` and `B`